# XML deserialize - How to replace a value property by a class while keeping compatibility?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a class with a large number of public properties, among them a number of float values:

```
public class Foo
{
    ...
    public float Bar {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

The class is XML serialized resulting in

```
<Foo ...(Schema stuff)... >
    ...
    <Bar>7.34</Bar>
    ...
</Foo>
```

In a subsequent version I needed to extend each float value with some additional non-serialized information so I created a new class:

```
public class ExtFloat
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
    private (other information)
}
```

In order to make the ExtFloat behave as a float in the thousands of lines of code already using the Foo class I added implicit converters:

```
public static implicit operator float(ExtFloat ef)
{
    return ef.Value;
}

public static implicit operator ExtFloat(float f)
{
    ExtFloat ef = new ExtFloat();
    ef.Value = f;
    return ef;
}
```

So far so good and it all works without having to change any of the code referring to the floats in foo. However the class now serializes into

```
<Foo ...(Schema stuff)... >
    ...
    <Bar>
        <Value>7.34</Value>
    </Bar>
    ...
</Foo>
```

which makes the hundreds of old XML files out there incompatible. So, my problem is: How do I Control the XML serialization process in order to make the Bar property in the existing XML files deserialize into the Value property of the new class?

There are in reality hundreds of properties like Bar in Foo so I want to keep the changes of each one of them at a minimum. So far I have only had to replace the type.

Comment: What kind of XML serialization are you using? `DataContract`s or "plain old vanilla" `XMLSerializer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the serialization based on the [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer), then there is a small trick for that.

Apply the [`XmlText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to the value property like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ExtFloat
{
    [XmlText]
    public float Value { get; set; }

    private (other information)
}
```

The `XmlSerializer` will then treat the `Value` property as the node value for all serialized properties of type `ExtFloat`.

Comment: Thanks @dymanoid, it works just fine except for a minor issue. It becomes culture dependent so I had to apply `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to my own conversion. However since my class is exposed through a PropertyGrid which _should_ be culture aware I had to add a separate property (with `[XmlIgnore]`) for the grid and mark the original as `[Browsable(false)]`